# Laravel show checkbox status in modal popup based on the value in datatable

Tags: laravel, datatables, modal-dialog

I have datatable in Laravel with some results and every record has Edit button. Here is the image of table.

[datatable with results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tncP.png)

Edit button opens modal dialog where I am able to Change specific record data.

Here is my HTML modal code:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="ajaxModel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modelHeading"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="CurrenciesForm" name="CurrenciesForm" class="form-horizontal">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_id" id="currency_id">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Name of currency</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name of currency" value="" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Currency code</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="code" placeholder="Enter currency code" value="" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label inline">Is this base currency?</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control inline" id="base" name="base" value="true" unchecked>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="saveBtn" value="create">Save
                     </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is JS code:

```
$(function () {

      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
    });

    var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "",
        columns: [
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'code', name: 'code'},
            {data: 'is_base_currency', name: 'is_base_currency'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [-1, -2, -3],
                className: 'dt-body-center'
            }
        ]
    });

    $('#createNewCurrency').click(function () {
        $('#saveBtn').val("create-Customer");
        $('#currency_id').val('');
        $('#CurrenciesForm').trigger("reset");
        $('#modelHeading').html("Create New Customer");
        $('#ajaxModel').modal('show');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.editCurrency', function () {
      var currency_id = $(this).data('id');
      console.log(document.getElementById('base').value);
      $.get("currencies" +'/' + currency_id +'/edit', function (data) {
          $('#modelHeading').html("Edit Customer");
          $('#saveBtn').val("edit-user");
          $('#ajaxModel').modal('show');
          $('#currency_id').val(data.id);
          $('#name').val(data.name);
          $('#code').val(data.code);
          $('#base').prop('checked', data.base);
          
      })
   });

    $('#saveBtn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).html('Save');
        
        $.ajax({
          data: $('#CurrenciesForm').serialize(),
          url: "",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {

              $('#CurrenciesForm').trigger("reset");
              $('#ajaxModel').modal('hide');
              table.draw();

          },
          error: function (data) {
              console.log('Error:', data);
              $('#saveBtn').html('Save');
          }
      });
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.deleteCurrency', function () {

        var currency_id = $(this).data("id");
        
        var txt;
        var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        if (r == true) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "currencies"+'/'+currency_id,
            success: function (data) {
                table.draw();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        
    });

  });
</script>
```

Also these are controller functions:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Currency::latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                    ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                           $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editCurrency">Edit</a>';
                           $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteCurrency" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?")">Delete</a>';
                            return $btn;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                    ->make(true);
        }

        return view('administration.currencies');
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->base != 'true' || $request->base != 'on'){
            $base = '';
        } 
        Currency::updateOrCreate(['id' => $request->currency_id],
                ['name' => $request->name, 'code' => $request->code ,'is_base_currency' => $request->base]);        

                return response()->json(['success'=>'Currency saved successfully!']);
    }

public function edit($id)
    {
        $Currency = Currency::find($id);
        return response()->json($Currency);
    }
```

I have a problem with checkbox field. When ever I open modal dialog for editing, the name and the code of fields gets passed to modal dialog but the field "Base" is not. I want to pass it to modal checkbox (if the value is "true" I want checkbox to be checked). Saving is working fine, I can change any data and checkbox and saving will be ok (if checkbox is checked it will save 'true' in DB) but I can not show the current value on modal pop up.

Also I would like to be able to show in the table in column "Base" value "YES" where the value in database is "true" but I am not sure how to do it since the table is populated though datatables.

Comment: thanks a lot for the comment but I am not very good with JS so I don't now where should I put it and do with it?

Comment: if checked the value od `data.base` should be 'true'

Answer (score 0):

- To check the checkbox use below code

  ```
  $('#base').prop('checked', (data.base == 'true' ? true : false));
  ```
- To modify the table column value, you can use Yajra datatable's `editColumn` method as below

  ```
   $data = Currency::latest()->get();
   return Datatables::of($data)
           ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                   $btn = 'id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editCurrency">Edit';
                   $btn = $btn.' id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteCurrency" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?")">Delete';
                   return $btn;
           })
           ->editColumn('base', function ($row) {
               return $row->base == 'true' ? 'Yes' : 'No';
           })
           ->rawColumns(['action', 'base'])
           ->make(true);
  ```